# how to programatically set an attribute value in angular ng-select

Tags: angular-ng-if, angular-ngselect

Im pretty new to Angular and Ive inherited an angular (11) app to work on.
Im having a problem with ng-select when the "multiple" attribute is set.  If multiple items are selected, the underlying object array is not being populated with the selected values, the array is always empty when passed into the component.  Ive done some research and one of the suggestions was that the bindValue attribute should be empty

```
bindValue=""
```

the component ive inherited has it set like this

```
bindValue="Id"
```

which works perfectly fine for a single selection, ie multiple set to false

I Dont want to break the existing code so I thought an option would be to set the bindValue attribute programatically based on the value of the 'multiple' attribute.  Ive tried this but it doesnt work

```
<ng-select #dropdown
         [multiple]="multiple"
         id={{formControlName}}
         [items]="list"
         bindLabel="Name"
         bindValue=*ngIf=[(multiple)] then ""; else "Id"
         (change)="onSelectionChange($event)"
         [closeOnSelect]="closeOnSelect"
         placeholder="Please Select"
         [formControl]="control"
         required={{isRequired}}>
```

this line doesnt work

```
bindValue=*ngIf=[(multiple)] then ""; else "Id"
```

I get an error on [(multiple)] telling me there is a missing attribute name and also for

then =""

and

else "Id"

Im new to angular so how would I be able to do this ?

any help would be greatly appreciated

*** Update ***

decided to approach this from a different angle, Ive made the following changes

```html
<div [ngClass]="setCssClass()">
  <!--<label for={{formControlName}}>{{label}}</label>-->
  <label htmlFor="{{formControlName}}">{{label}}</label>
  <ng-select #dropdown
             [multiple]="multiple"
             id={{formControlName}}
             [items]="list"
             bindLabel="Name"
             [bindValue]="setBindValue()"
             (change)="onSelectionChange($event)"
             [closeOnSelect]="closeOnSelect"
             placeholder="Please Select"
             [formControl]="control"
             required={{isRequired}}>
  </ng-select>
  <app-control-validation [control]="control" *ngIf="isRequired"></app-control-validation>
</div>
```

and in the underlying typescript file

```
setBindValue() {
var bv = 'Id';
bv = this.multiple === true ? "" : "Id";
return bv;
```

}

This works and I get bindValue attribute set according to the multiple attribute value, so if multiple is true, bindValue will be an empty string, otherwise it will be "Id"

However, I still have the same problem, the array associated with the dropdown is always empty !  Im stumped, how on earth do I get the multiple values selected ??  help...

** UPDATE **

Anyone ? I just cant get this to work, I could really do with some help